# Writing curved text on an arc (PHP)

Tags: php, gd

So I Googled and found out how to draw an arc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php

The only problem is how do I write text $margin pixels from the arc that is curved.

Centre aligned @ $degrees.

Here is an example: http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3667/scan0001fe.jpg

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple PHP solution found at http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/57542-image-manipulation-skewing-text-text-on-a-curve/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/PHP/alt.php/2004-12/0061.html

Comment: Looks like a start, I wonder how to centre align it @ x degrees though?

Answer (score 0):

Imagick has native support for curved text