# Create CircleText on image with Imagemagick (convert)

Tags: imagemagick

I've a round image and I need to put some circle text on it.

[image]

The text is from the frontend where the preview is build with CircleType.js (http://circletype.labwire.ca/) a jQuery Plugin.

```
$("span#text").circleType({
        radius: 102,
        dir: -1
});
```

I checked http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/ without a solution

currently I get this result

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lnhaF23.png]

with the following code:

```
convert \
 -background  none \
 -font Candice \
 -pointsize 32 \
 -fill navy label:\"A short TEST text\" \
 -rotate 180 \
 -distort Arc '270 180' \
  outfile.png
```

but it isn't ever the same radius / distance to the border, base on the text length like in the first image.

Can somebody help me, please

Comment: How is it supposed to look? And maybe use a yellow background on here so we can see the extent of the image.

Comment: Try adjusting the values to see what you get; thr imagemagick options are on this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#distort

Comment: The code you have is creating some text on a rectangular background, rotating it 180 degrees then distorting it. The result will depend on the font size and the amount of characters.

Comment: i've added the preview image i need to rebuild with convert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913342/writing-curved-text-on-an-arc-php here is a solution without imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but you can hopefully see how to get there from this.
Like this maybe:

```
convert \
 -background  yellow \
 -pointsize 64 \
 -fill navy label:"A longer test text" \
 -rotate 180 \
 -distort arc '270 180' \
 -trim +repage -resize 400x400 -gravity south -extent 400x400! outfile.png
```

[image]

Comment: not realy what i need, you use my bad convert with `-rotate 180 -distort arc '270 180'` that was the a example from the imagemagick page

Comment: you are resizeing the image after adding the text and then the fontsize is incorrect - thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I still can't tell what you want:-) You say you want 400x400 but you have posted an image that is 897x757 with a clear background so that the extent is not readily discernible.

Comment: i need ever the same radius and distance for the text to the border of the circle, sorry for my incorrect image size in my question